# RxJs V4 Operator that combines forkJoin and map

Tags: javascript, operators, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to find an operator that lets me handle the operations performed by `forkJoin` and `map` in one step instead of two.

My input is an array of observables with varying lengths and I would like to wait until all of them have completed and then create a computed result from the observable outputs that I can subscribe to.

I haven't come across one that allows for those requirements and takes an array as input.

Below an example of a use case:

```
const observable1 = Rx.Observable.create(
  (observer) => {
    observer.onNext([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    observer.complete();
  }
);

const observable2 = Rx.Observable.create(
  (observer) => {
    observer.onNext([5, 6, 7, 8]);
    observer.complete();
  }
);

Rx.Observable.magigOperator([observable1, observable2])
   .subscribe(
     (result) => console.log
   );
```

Now the result I am trying to get is an output of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`;
I can achieve it by using `forkJoin` and `map` and running a flatten function, but I was wondering whether there is a single operator that allows me to do this in one go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `map`, you can just pass a result selector function as a last argument of `forkJoin`, e.g.:

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2], _.concat)
```

Also note that `observable1` and `observable2` in your example do not complete which prevents `forkJoin` from emitting the result.

Comment: Oh brilliant! Didn't know about the selector function on forkJoin! That does the job. Thanks

Comment: I just changed the example in the answer from `_.flatten` to `_.concat` to match selector signature. Here `lodash` functions are used.

Comment: It is deprecated now, use `forkJoin().pipe(map())`

Answer (score 0):

last argument of forkJoin is a function that can manipulate the results from observables. try something like this:

```
const observable1 = Rx.Observable.create(
    (observer) => {
        observer.next([1, 2, 3, 4]);
        observer.complete();
    }
);

const observable2 = Rx.Observable.create(
    (observer) => {
        observer.next([5, 6, 7, 8]);
        observer.complete();
    }
);

Rx.Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2], (res1, res2) => [...res1, ...res2]).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

notice that observer has next no onNext method. Also if you want to you forkJoin the observer has to complete.

Comment: Using rxjs v4 so next is onNext for me

Answer (score 0):

By the way you can create your observables like this (cold observable are automatically completed when values are emitted):

```
const observable1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4]);
const observable2 = Rx.Observable.of([5,6,7,8]);

Observable.forkJoin(observable1, observable2, (...args)=> [].concat(...args));
```

Thanks [kit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794100/kit) for you answer.